# SpringBoot: Unit Test with Cassandra

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'd like to test my SpringBoot application that uses cassandra as a CrudRepository. I ended up with

```
/*
 * https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/Spring-for-Cassandra-unit
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan
@ContextConfiguration(value = { "classpath:/default-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@CassandraDataSet(value = { "setupTables.cql" }, keyspace = "keyspaceToCreate")
@CassandraUnit
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MyCassandraRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        System.out.println(repo.findAll());

    }

}
```

with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE MY_CASSANDRA_ENTRY (
  MY_CASS_STRING varchar PRIMARY KEY
)
```

This leads to

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9142 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
```

If I use an older version of cassandra-unit-spring

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

it ends with a NullPointerException because the value repo is not injected.

Sources https://github.com/StephanPraetsch/spring.boot.cassandra.unit.test

Comment: Witch versions of spring boot and spring data cassandra do you use? in some versions there are conflicts regarding some netty depencendies. if you are using gradle or maven taking a look at the dependency trees might help

Answer (score 3):

CassandraUnit starts on port `9142`. Spring Boot defaults to port `9042`. You need to set the port and the keyspace name so the Cassandra driver can pickup the right connection details.

You need to change two things in your test:

1. Please use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. That enables a couple of other things like configuration property support which you will need in step 2.
2. Create `src/test/resources/application.properties` and set the port and keyspace name.

```
spring.data.cassandra.port=9142
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=keyspaceToCreate
```

This will configure the correct port and keyspace.

Alternatively, you could specify properties using

```
@SpringBootTest({"spring.data.cassandra.port=9142",
                 "spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=keyspaceToCreate"})
```